# How to save L.Control.layer states for authorized users

Tags: leaflet

I have a working map leaflet controlling layers with L.Control.layer.

My problem is that it is necessary to make "Profiles" for users, that is, each user authorized on the site can select layers in L.Control.layer and save these layers in his "Profile", this profile can be unlimited , and he can choose which profile to be on. Let me explain, when he selects one or another profile, he is found in L.Control.layer those layers that he saves.

I am using Postgres database as data.

The user can also modify these profiles.

I know that I can use something like this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/sQuEy/4/)

```js
var i, checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

function save() {
    for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        localStorage.setItem(checkboxes[i].value, checkboxes[i].checked); 
    }
}

function load_() {
    for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = localStorage.getItem(checkboxes[i].value) === 'true' ? true:false;
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="chB1" /> Checkbox 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="chB2" /> Checkbox 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="chB3" /> Checkbox 3<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="chB4" /> Checkbox 4<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="chB5" /> Checkbox 5<br /> 
<button onclick="save()">SAVE</button>

<button onclick="load_()">LOAD</button>
```

but this is saved locally, and the user can log in from another device and nothing will be saved

Can this be implemented?